# PHP: double output of php errors / warnings / notices

Tags: php, error-reporting

If I execute the following script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
trigger_error('test notice', E_USER_NOTICE);
die('end of script');
```

I get the following output:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  test notice in <b>path/to/script/test.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
end of scriptPHP Notice:  test notice in path/to/script/test.php on line 3
```

The script was executed on IIS8 with PHP Version 5.4.19.

The http status code returned is 200.

"display_errors" is set to "On" and "error_reporting" to "E_ALL" in the php.ini file. So the first line of the script is just for clarification.

The behaviour is the same with all error reporting constants (E_ERROR, E_WARNING, etc.).

Does anyone know where the second output of the notice comes from? And especially how the get rid of it?

Comment: The script turns on the error reporting for php scripts. See the file `test.php` on line 3 for the error.

Comment: No idea about IIS but command-line PHP prints error messages to both stdout and stderr. That seems to be the case as well for your web server set up.

Comment: have u tried by commenting the first line `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Comment: Yes I tried to commenting it out. But the error_reporting function just defines which error types (levels) will be outputed not if they realy be send as output. The display_errors directive defines that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue I had to change the base settings of the site in IIS:
"Connect As" with the IIS_USER and the double output of php error messages were gone!
I still don't know why, but at least it works.

Answer (score 2):

If you set both

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

The errors will be doubled:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: test in
> /path/to/script.php
> on line 8
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: test in
> /path/to/script.php
> on line 8

Try turning one or the other off or a [set a custom error handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

Answer (score 0):

First line in your script

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Sets PHP to report all errors and with ***`display_errors`*** directive enabled in your PHP configuration which sets PHP to print errors to the screen, then no need to your second line which duplicates the output.

Comment: Sorry but that's not true. The "error_reporting()" function does not output anything, it just overwrites the "error_reporting" directive set in the php.ini. And it does not cause the second output.